# Aggregate by two columns and count occurrences of distinct values in third column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, aggregate, frequency

I have a dataset in pandas, with four columns (year, month, day, register).

df_registration

[data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJFkk.png)

I want to group the data by year and month, and then count for each month in a year how many 'yes' and how many 'no' there were (or at least how many 'yes').

Image of df with expected result:

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61yTF.png)

I have tried doing group_by + count,

```
g = df_registration.groupby(["year", "month"])
monthly_counts = g.aggregate({"register": pd.Series.value_counts })
```

but the outputs do not give the desired outcome, they just count the number of both register values.

Image of df with failed attempt:

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Opn.png)

I cannot get it to work as I want...

EDIT!____________ solution _________________

The code from alex smolyakov in the comment works!

counts = df_registration.groupby(["year", "month"]["register"].value_counts()

[the code output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2enn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counts = df_registration.groupby(["year", "month"])["register"].value_counts()
```

does it help ?

Comment: Yes, now I get the counts for each input. Thank you!